# One-line jQuery innerHtml swapper

Tags: jquery, swap

Since we can't do some `$('el1').swap('el2')` with pure jQuery (yet?), I ask ye fellow coders if you have enough creativity to turn this

```
var temp = $('el1').html();
$('el1').html($('el2').html());
$('el2').html(temp);
```

into an one-liner.

*(I myself tried many ideas that use `toggle()`, but always ended with way increased html content to compensate. Gave up... twas fun, nonetheless.)*

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "micro-optimization"?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Yes, yes, of course. As well as with the term "code golf".

Comment: `$('el1').swap('el2')` would make more sense.

Comment: @Musa Agreed. Initially I thought it off from `$('el1,el2').toggle()`, being 'el1' and 'el2' opposite in visibility. I edited it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the code more readable, let's assume the two containers are represented by jQuery objects `A` and `B`.

Then :

```
A.wrapInner('<div class="A"/>').append(B.wrapInner('<div class="B"/>').find(".B")).find(".A").appendTo(B).contents().unwrap().end().end().end().find(".B").contents().unwrap();
```

... which is a totally monstrous one-liner, but that's what was asked for!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sHsTu/)**

Even better, this simplifies to :

```
A.wrapInner('<div class="A"/>').append(B.contents()).find(".A").appendTo(B).contents().unwrap();
```

... which is a less monstrous one-liner!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sHsTu/1/)**

The knack is to avoid `.html()` at any point, which would deny you the opportunity of further jQuery method chaining.

Comment: `$('el1').wrapInner('<div class="A"/>').append($('el2').contents()).find(".A").appendTo($('el2')).contents().unwrap();` This makes my brain hurt a bit, but this is it, and it works! Amazing one-liner!!

Comment: Yup that's it, substituting for `A` and `B`. Don't feel too bad about it making your brain hurt. Mine was not completely pain-free while working it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a jQuery that swap, you can create your own call like that :

```
$.fn.swap = function(el){
    var temp = this.html(), $el = el instanceof $ ? el : $(el);
    this.html($el.html());
    $el.html(temp);
    return this;
}
```

Then call it like that :

```
$(el).swap('jQuery selector');
$(el).swap(jQueryObject); //alternative
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just roll out your own swap function?

```
function swapHTML(el1, el2) {
  var temp = $(el1).html();
  $(el1).html($(el2).html());
  $(el2).html(temp);
}
```

This way, you can just call this as many times as you want, as a one-liner with different parameters:

```
swapHTML('el1', 'el2');
swapHTML('el3', 'el4');
...
```